# How to build a sequence 2 cols by n rows based on a col range of values paired with a col of times to repeat the value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How to build a sequence 2 cols by n rows based on a col range of values paired with a col of times to repeat the value.

Also the options to give and starting index would be good.

The values will be =IMAGE("url") so the images need to work when the sequence is built.

Definition

```
Index | 1
----------
Value | NR
----------
img1  | 5
----------
img2  | 4
----------
img3  | 3
```

Desired Result (With starting index 1)

```
img1 | img1
-----------
img1 | img1
-----------
img1 | img2
-----------
img2 | img2
-----------
img2 | img3
-----------
img3 | img3
```

Desired Result (With starting index 3)

```
     |     
-----------
     | img1
-----------
img1 | img1
-----------
img1 | img1
-----------
img2 | img2
-----------
img2 | img2
-----------
img3 | img3
-----------
img3 |
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the formula for the case where starting index is 1:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(sequence((sum(B2:B)+1)/2,2,0),{sumif(row(B2:B),"<="&row(B2:B),B2:B)-B2:B,A2:A},2))
```

[image]

The idea is to look up the value generated by Sequence (0 to 11) in the cumulative sum of the NR's up to the previous row to the corresponding image.

**EDIT**

Here is the updated formula to allow for a start index>1:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(sequence((sum(B2:B)+C2)/2,2,1)>=C2,vlookup(sequence((sum(B2:B)+C2)/2,2,1)-C2,{sumif(row(B2:B),"<="&row(B2:B),B2:B)-B2:B,A2:A},2),""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've added a `+ 1` to all `C2` occurrences in Tom's formula just to make the empty cells added match the `index` number.

```
=ArrayFormula(if(sequence((sum(B2:B)+(C2+1))/2,2,1)>=(C2+1),vlookup(sequence((sum(B2:B)+(C2+1))/2,2,1)-(C2+1),{sumif(row(B2:B),"<="&row(B2:B),B2:B)-B2:B,A2:A},2),""))
```

Works perfectly

Many Thanks Tom!